# Store data in backend(table) from JComboBox

Tags: sql, swing, exception

What is the syntax error here?

[image: What is the syntax error here?]

I'm getting this syntax error. I want to store data in the database from *Jcombobox*. `Foodname` and `Qty` are my table column names.

```
String Foodname=starter.getSelectedItem().toString();
String Qty=starterqty.getText();
    try{
           pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into order values(?,?)");
           pst.setString(1,Foodname);
           pst.setString(2,Qty);
           pst.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is saved");

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex); 
    }
```

Comment: The error says that you wrote a wrong query. However, what does it mean you want to store from JComboBox to database? You don't know How retrieve value of JComboBox? You don't know how to write you're query? Show your code, what you did. Nobody can help you this way

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to retrieve JComboBox values into the database. I've used, //combobox.getSelectedItem().toString() to get the data. But as you can see above, I'm getting SQL syntax error. I've posted the code that I've used for retrieving data from JComboBox into database.
I need to know why am I getting SQL syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a table named `order`, in `MySQL/MariaDB` databases `order` is a reserved word, you should either change your table name or use quotes like below,

```
insert into `order` values(?,?)
```

Or simply change table name,

```
insert into `some_other_name` values(?,?)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering where I was going wrong. Big help, cheers!

Comment: @darksight see ? when you explain your problem well and you show the code, you will always find someone who can help you!

Comment: I posted my code beforehand along with my error. Anyways thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The error it tells you that your query is not valid

Comment: But where am I going wrong? what is the syntax error here?